# Aggregate if array property contains an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Description**

---

Working on a blog app, where users can like a blog based on ip.
IP's are stored in the `likes` property of the `blog` document.

I want to write a query to add an extra boolean property named `liked` which is true if the `likes` array include the input ip.

**Question**

---

How to add a new boolean property to the query results, which is true, if an array property of the document contains a certain input object?

**Example**

---

Current data in the database is:

```
 [
     { _id:123123,
      title: "title here",
      desc: "some other text here",
      likes: [
       {ip: "10.0.0.1"},
       {ip: "0.1.1.1"},
       // ... a lot more {ip: "..."}
      ]
     },
     { 
        // the next blog document...
     },
     // all other blog documents...
 ]
```

What I expect from the query output is:

```
[
 {   _id:123123,
      title: "title here",
      desc: "some other text here",
      liked: true // if the array contains {ip: "10.0.0.1"}
      ]
 },
 {
      _id:2,
      title: "another"
      desc: "some text",
      liked: false
 },
//...
]
```

**Notes**

---

I am using he official MongoDB driver for NodeJS. ([see documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/tutorials/aggregation/))

What I came up with so far:

```
   dbo.collection('blogs')
                     .aggregate([{ $project: { 
                        title:1,
                        desc:1,
                        liked: {$cond: {if: {// TODO: not sure what to write here...}},
                     }}])
```

Comment: Try `liked: {$in:["10.0.0.1", "$likes.ip"]}`

Comment: `MongoError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing`

Comment: Looks like you have missing likes array field for some documents. Try `{$in:["10.0.0.1", {$ifNull:["$likes.ip", []]}]}`

Comment: worked! thanks @Veeram

Comment: Whilst you "can" do this, for performance reasons I generally would not advise it. If all you really need is confirmation that a matching entry exists in an array then it "should" be more performant to use [`$elemMatch (projection)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/). Does not return `true/false`, but it does "strip" the array of any entries other than the desired element. i.e `dbo.collection.find({}, { "likes": { "$elemMatch": { "ip": "10.0.0.1" } } })`. That's considerably less overhead that manipulating every document in the collection via `$project`.